# How to disable auto-compile on save in ASP.NET Core applications

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, tooling

I have ASP.NET Core application running on the full .NET framework. I use Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 and VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 for .NET Core 1.0.1. When I save some document in Visual Studio, compilation all of my projects starts. Is it possible to disable this behavior? I want to compile my code just when I want.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the compiler is running on each save?

Comment: Example: CTRL+F5 -> Project starts to build, new window is opened. I go back to Visual Studio (I do any change), CTRL+S, building starts again with message "Project XX.XX.Data (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) will be compiled because expected inputs are missing". I go to browser (I just want to see my website), project starts to build again with message "Project will be compiled because inputs were modified". I go to VS, use CTRL+S and project starts to build again with the same message (I changed nothing). Everytime I use CTRL+S, project starts to build again and again and again.